# How can I set skew image with html and css

Tags: html, css, image

I just newbie in web programming.

This is what I mean:

http://s12.postimg.org/tc25a1zsd/test.jpg

Can you help me close this case?

you can download the part of image here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2lri_YI_98jalA3Vkc3TEdNZDQ/edit?usp=sharing

here's my attempt:

CSS:

> ```
> body
>
> {
> font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
> font-size: 12px;
> font-color: #000000;
> background-color: #FFFFFF;
> }
>
> #header
> {
> width: 1000px;
> height: 365px;
> margin-right: auto;
> margin-left: auto;
> background-image: url('images/BerlinBack.png');
> }
>
> #left-image
> {
> float: left;
> background: #999999;
> }
>
> #middle-image
> {
> float: left;
> margin-left: 200px;
> }
>
> #right-image
> {
> float: left;
> margin-left: 400px;
> }
> ```

```
HTML:
```

> < div id = "header"> < div id = "left-image"> < div id = "middle-image"> < div id = "right-image"> < /div>

Comment: Have you made any attempts at doing this yourself?

Comment: it's not a job board.

Comment: I try make it in many way, but never succes :(

Comment: Show us the code you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this with transform rotate:

```
li {
    list-style: none;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 25px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

li:first-child {
    background: red;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
    background: yellow;
}

li:last-child {
    background: green;
}

ul {
    height: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Check the following fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/fQfd5/2/

Answer (score 1):

Use the 
`transform:rotate(degree)` property of css3
Depending on the browser you're using, use `-ms-transform:rotate(degree)` or `-webkit-transform:rotate(degree)` for IE and Chrome/Safari respectively